# Using static variables Vs automatic doesn't impact the run-time performance

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, static-variables

GCC keeps me baffled by its strange optimizations. The execution speeds of the two functions below (`calculate_with_static_vars` and `calculate_with_stack_vars`) don't have any meaningful difference.

Here is the MRE code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cmath>
#include <chrono>


// just a simple timer, DON't PAY ATTENTION TO THIS
struct ScopedTimer
{
    const std::chrono::time_point< std::chrono::steady_clock > start { std::chrono::steady_clock::now( ) };
          std::chrono::time_point< std::chrono::steady_clock > end;

    ScopedTimer( ) = default;
    ~ScopedTimer( )
    {
        end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now( );
        std::clog << "\nTimer took "
                  << std::chrono::duration< double, std::milli>( end - start ).count( )
                  << " ms\n";
    }
    ScopedTimer( const ScopedTimer& ) = delete;
    ScopedTimer& operator=( const ScopedTimer& ) = delete;
};

// this is the custom struct
struct Point3D
{
    float x, y, z;
};

// the candidate 1
float calculate_with_static_vars( const Point3D point5 )
{
    static constexpr Point3D point1 { 1.5f, 4.83f, 2.01f }; // static vars
    static constexpr Point3D point2 { 2.5f, 5.83f, 3.01f };
    static constexpr Point3D point3 { 3.5f, 6.83f, 4.01f };
    static constexpr Point3D point4 { 4.5f, 7.83f, 5.01f };

    const auto dist1 { std::hypot( point1.x - point2.x,
                                   point1.y - point2.y,
                                   point1.z - point2.z ) };

    const auto dist2 { std::hypot( point2.x - point3.x,
                                   point2.y - point3.y,
                                   point2.z - point3.z ) };

    const auto dist3 { std::hypot( point3.x - point4.x,
                                   point3.y - point4.y,
                                   point3.z - point4.z ) };

    const auto dist4 { std::hypot( point4.x - point5.x,
                                   point4.y - point5.y,
                                   point4.z - point5.z ) };

    return dist1 + dist2 + dist3 + dist4;
}

// the candidate 2
float calculate_with_stack_vars( const Point3D point5 )
{
    constexpr Point3D point1 { 1.5f, 4.83f, 2.01f }; // stack vars
    constexpr Point3D point2 { 2.5f, 5.83f, 3.01f };
    constexpr Point3D point3 { 3.5f, 6.83f, 4.01f };
    constexpr Point3D point4 { 4.5f, 7.83f, 5.01f };

    const auto dist1 { std::hypot( point1.x - point2.x,
                                   point1.y - point2.y,
                                   point1.z - point2.z ) };

    const auto dist2 { std::hypot( point2.x - point3.x,
                                   point2.y - point3.y,
                                   point2.z - point3.z ) };

    const auto dist3 { std::hypot( point3.x - point4.x,
                                   point3.y - point4.y,
                                   point3.z - point4.z ) };

    const auto dist4 { std::hypot( point4.x - point5.x,
                                   point4.y - point5.y,
                                   point4.z - point5.z ) };

    return dist1 + dist2 + dist3 + dist4;
}

// a function that decides which of the above functions to call based on the branch_flag
inline float testFunc( const bool branch_flag, const bool arg_flag )
{
    bool isStatic { branch_flag };
    Point3D point2;
    if ( arg_flag ) { point2 = { 3.5f, 7.33f, 9.04f }; }
    else            { point2 = { 2.5f, 6.33f, 8.04f }; }

    float dist;
    constexpr size_t numOfIterations { 1'000'000'000 };

    if ( isStatic )
    {
        for ( size_t counter { }; counter < numOfIterations; ++counter )
        {
            dist = calculate_with_static_vars( point2 );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for ( size_t counter { }; counter < numOfIterations; ++counter )
        {
            dist = calculate_with_stack_vars( point2 );
        }
    }

    return dist;
}


int main( )
{
    bool branch_flag;
    std::cin >> branch_flag;
    bool arg_flag;
    std::cin >> arg_flag;

    float dist;
    {
    ScopedTimer timer;
    dist = testFunc( branch_flag, arg_flag );
    }

    std::cout << "Sum of the distances of the four points: " << dist << '\n';
}
```

The two functions are doing the same work (calculating the distances between 4 points and returning their sum) the only difference they have is that one uses static variables meanwhile the other one uses stack variables (a.k.a automatic).

The user has two enter two boolean values on the console (1st one is for deciding which function to run and the 2nd one which is not important is for deciding which argument to pass to the function being called). Like this:

```
true    // runs the function with static vars
true    // passes the first point to it
```

or

```
false   // runs the function with automatic vars
true    // passes the first point to it
```

And then the loop inside `testFunc` calls the chosen function **1 billion** times.

Now one might wonder why is there this much bloat in this code. The reason is that I wanted to prevent GCC from doing aggressive compile-time optimizations. Otherwise, it would make the two functions implicitly `consteval` and that would defeat the purpose of my test.

So the question is how are these functions taking the same amount of time to run (~22 sec on my old machine)? Shouldn't the static version be considerably faster since it allocates storage and then initializes its variables only once?

Comment: the two do the same thing, why expect a big difference?

Comment: Maybe remove the `constexpr` attributes and re-try? Can't see why, with that, any "allocation" is needed at all.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I believe that coping values from the text section of the program onto the stack frame of the second function should cause a performance hit. I have made about 10 `constexpr` variables `static` (just added the `static` keyword to their declaration!!) in one of my programs and it resulted in a ~%15 performance boost. I don't know why it doesn't happen for this program.

Comment: @digito_evo `constexpr` is probably the "culprit". If you use `constexpr`, the fact that the variables are static or not probaby doesn't matter anymore to the compiler. Try to remove `constexpr` and see what happens. Also look at the generated asembly code.

Comment: As `constexpr`, the non-static structures don't need to be initialized on each call, because they will always be the same. They may be stored differently than the static ones, so the non-static function may use more stack ... but the stack is already allocated, so whether a function need 2 bytes of stack or 2,000 bytes makes little or no difference: you're just adjusting the (single) SP register.

Comment: Well, look at line 55-56 of the generated assembly: https://godbolt.org/z/3M68r9dso

Comment: @Bob__ Heh ... that's a pretty smart compiler! :-)

Comment: @Bob__ Wow that is crazy. How does it know?! So after all this time, I was practically calling the same function over and over again.

Comment: @digito_evo Also remove the `-O2` from https://godbolt.org/z/3M68r9dso and you'll see that the generated assembly code of both functions is basically identical.

Comment: @digito_evo Even when the constant in both functions are different, the generated assembly code is effectively the same: https://godbolt.org/z/9YMbacY1M. The constants are stored in the same segment. In the second case, there is no reason to explicitly store them to the stack with optimizations.

Comment: @Daniel Langr So what I understood by looking at the assembly is that the constants expressions are loaded from the text segment (hence the usage of rip register) directly to the SSE registers (xmm0, xmm1, etc) and then the `hypot` is called. Thus the call stack usage is minimized significantly. Is this true?

Comment: @digito_evo Learn about the _as-if rule_. It basically says that the implementation should generate machine code with the observable behavior that is prescribed to the source code by the C++ standard. That's it. The standard does not have any concept of stack or data or code segment. The as-if rule applies for both your functions. If they have the same observable behavior, then a compiler is free to generate the same machine code. Those constants may be hardcoded in the assembly as immediates as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So the question is how are these functions taking the same amount of time to run (~22 sec on my old machine)?

Because they can be compiled to identical assembly.

> Shouldn't the static version be considerably faster since it allocates storage and then initializes its variables only once?

No. The variables are compile time constant. In practice, the compiler can avoid providing them any storage whatsoever.

With constant-folding optimisation, both functions are effectively equivalent to:

```
return 5.19615269  // dist1 + dist2 + dist3
    + std::hypot(
          4.5f  - point5.x,
          7.83f - point5.y,
          5.01f - point5.z);
```